# Why angular data-binding not working with jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm working on the angular tutorial project ---- angular-phonecat, and I got to the step-5.

Out of curiosity, I replace the original angular ajax method with jquery ajax method and left the rest untouched. 
After that I found I can get the right data from server but the data-binding never works.

Here is my code :

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    //$http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    //  $scope.phones = data;
    //});
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "phones/phones.json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        global: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $scope.phones = data;
        }
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

Why would this happen? Am I miss anything important?

Comment: Why are you using ajax rather that $http service?

Comment: As I mentioned, just out of curiosity. :-)

Comment: I didnt read it carefully, my bad! :-)

Comment: `$http` is better integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle. The other benefit of `$http` is that it returns `$q` promises which are also better integrated with the digest cycle.

Comment: Yeah, I got a lot to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because jQuery's ajax function is not within the **angular digest cycle**. To fix this use `$scope.$apply();` to run the cycle explicitly:

```
$scope.phones = data;
$scope.$apply();
```

Also, one piece of advice: try to use as less jQuery(use it for DOM manipulations mainly) as possible otherwise you won't be able to learn the 'angular' way.

Comment: I would wrap the scope variable assignment inside of scope.apply, as outlined in this article: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer and suggestion. I'm pretty familiar with jquery but new to the angular, so cant stop thinking in jquery.

Comment: I think this link would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: It sure will be! Thx, again.

Comment: And may I ask why the other two respondent delete their answers?

Comment: To avoid duplicate answers. They were saying the same thing as me.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do `$scope.$apply()` to let angular know to run watch/digest cycle if code is run outside of angular.

$http is monitored by angular where as ajax is not.