# How to update an object value from a function during page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

In the code below I have an object named $scope.dateRange with property fromDate and toDate. I used the object at view as  model, and I am updating the values of the objects at GetVoucherLatestDate() function. But it is not updating, it is remain as null that I have declared before the function, because it is asynchronous.

What I need is to get the dates value from the function to show in the view during the page load? I need the help desperately.

```
$scope.dateRange = {
    fromDate: null,
    toDate: null
};
$scope.gap = -2;
$scope.budgetResponsiblePersonId = null;
$scope.overAllStatusList = [];
console.log("DatePre", $scope.dateRange);
$scope.GetVoucherLatestDate = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'Accounts/MISAccountDashboard/GetVoucherLatestDate/',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.getFromDate = response.data;
        console.log("Response Data", response.data);
        console.log("$scope.data", $scope.getFromDate);
        dateData = ;       
        $scope.dateRange = {
            fromDate: $filter('dateFiltering')($scope.getFromDate[0].PostingDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
            toDate: $filter('dateFiltering')($scope.getFromDate[0].PostingDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
        };
    });

};
$scope.GetVoucherLatestDate();
```

Comment: did you check the value for `$filter('dateFiltering' ($scope.getFromDate[0].PostingDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')` in console log?

Comment: Do you see expected value in console.log("Response Data", response.data); also please share the model code of binding.

Comment: @StaticVariable Yes I checked it.

Comment: @Shaheryar.Akram Yes U checked it inside the function.

Comment: well I don't see any problem unless you have made some mistake in binding the model in view. And just for curiosity, are you somehow cleaning  `$scope.getFromDate` just after the function?

Comment: @Shaheryar.Akram I am not cleaning `$scope.getFromDate` after the function. it has created inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you have bind the model in UI, however `$scope.$apply()` should propagate your changes to UI.

Comment: confirmation and question for more clarification should go as comment not as answer.

Comment: If u provide some example.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun I think he means after your $scope.dateRange = in $scope.GetVoucherLatestDate put $scope.$apply();  probable reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108913/changing-angularjs-scope-variables-from-an-inside-function